# Solr Nutch integration on Cloudera

Tags: solr, nutch, cloudera

Has any one been able to get nutch and solr to work together on a Cloudera cluster?

The usual instruction is to get the `schema.xml` from nutch and replace the orginal one in solr. After that

```
/opt/apache-nutch-1.9/bin/crawl urls crawl http://localhost:8983/solr 2 -depth 3 -topN 100
```

will index the crawled pages in solr. However, in the Cloudera cluster, the `schema.xml` sits in zookeeper.

After I replace the zookeeper copy with the one from nutch, the solr cluster no long works. One out the two solr servers in the cluster crashes right after restart.

I can not find any instructions on the web. Does any one know about this?

Comment: Did you try to merge the schema.xml from nutch to schema.xml in zookeeper? I mean just replace the field names from the nutch one to cloudera. I already did such process and I had not any problem with indexing to solr.

Comment: I need to return to this after so long. From your response, it seems you are saying you edited the schema.xml content in the znode? how did you do that? I don't see any editing commands you can use. I don't even see any commands for copying a file into a znode path.